# How to check when a div resizes, using Javascript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

So I've got a web applcation in the midst of wireframing, but I've run into an issue that requires a technical solution before I can solidify this model; that being:

- **Fig. #1** User creates new 'text-field'
  element (a div with a max-width.)
  User then begins typing into said
  element until...
- **Fig. #2** The element reaches it's
  max-width, the text drops to a new line and a 'new' background image (in
  the form of another div) is created (with it's opacity and position animated for effect) to accommodate the larger element sze.

[image: UX model concept]

This is a rough outline of the intended functionality (given at this moment, I'm not sure how to have a text-field that behaves like a div with max-width yet) but ***I'm curious about how to create the event handler for the 2nd step***; I thought about checking on every 'keydown' event, but that seems inefficient...

Does anyone have any advice or ideas for tackling something like this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MSIE an onresize should fire.

Comment: Supposedly 'onresize' would work for div's in Internet Explorer, but I can't afford to take this approach... it (unprecedentedly) only works in IE.

Comment: So you like to ignore the option one browser gives you with exactly the thing you need(onresize on elements)? Weird! You can try to work with the suggested key-events(did they fire if there will data be cut or pasted?). Setting a interval to check the dimensions? Intervals never be a good practice if you can avoid them! There are other, much better solutions. The one I posted for MSIE. The other is DOMSubtreeModified, supported by gecko and webkit. It's not that smart like the IE-onresize, but works good. Check out the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/fJmGZ/

Comment: No disrespect of course! This app needs to function perfectly on all browsers, so an IE-only solution is frankly irrelevant; your follow up answer (and example) look great! I'd take back the -1 if I could... I'm examining it closer now, and reading up on DOMSubtreeModified.

Comment: Thats what I mean. As there is no perfect unique cross-browser-solution you need to take the best every browser will offer to you :)

Comment: I think you've gotten me to the next step of development--I hope you don't mind if I send you a direct message with any follow up questions I may have ;)

Comment: No, I don't mind, but are here on SO any ways to send direct messages? I haven't found any yet^^

Comment: ok, got your adress(maybe you like to remove it). I go to sleep now, send you my adress tomorrow;)

Answer (score 3):

The 'keydown' or 'keyup' event is the first thing that comes to mind. If you decide to do it this way you will have to 
check for the html elements size each time and compare it to the old (save in a variable) one.

Easiest way seems to be to bind a handler to the html element and let it fire when the size changes.
I do not know if such an event exists, but if then thats the way to go.

(+1 for your very descriptive Question)

Comment: I'm still not even sure how to get a resizable text area / input field, but the 'keydown/up' approach... what if they press and hold a letter--wouldn't that just break my model?

Comment: On KeyDown set a JS interval to keep checking the input length and resize acordingly. Then on KeyUp remove the interval and do one last check in the input. This will solve your Press and Hold issue.

Comment: @Brady - nice... that seems like it'd work great! It seems like it's a consensus that 'keydown/up' down is the way to go?

Answer (score 2):

You could try using the CSS3 transition functionality:
http://slides.html5rocks.com/#slide42
That way the elements you want can be animated by the browser itself.

Disclaimer: Obviously, this doesn't work with more complicated effects.

Comment: That's pretty neat--how is this much different than using Jquery to animate it? I don't know how comfortable I am switching to HTML5 just yet... from what I understand, it's a completely different doctype with a different set of compatibility issues.

Comment: @JulianDroid - Dont get confused by HTML5 and CSS3 they are two seperate things. Just be aware though if you start using CSS3 now all IE browser wont see the fancy new CSS3.

Comment: It's not very different, other than the fact that you can set an animation duration for every possible event.  I.e. you don't have to watch for when the characters reach the end of the line, you just tell it "when you try to resize, do it with an animation".

Comment: @Brady - I'm quite familiar with the limitations and cross-browser compatibility issues of CSS, but last I checked, HTML5 wasn't as widely supported as the XHTML 1.0 Strict doctype I normally work with.

Comment: Yeah, I see what you're saying... for this particular project though, I need the separate background image--it has to be a separate element that is created/animated; I already know how to handle all that... it's the event handler, and re-sizable text field that are breaking my brain at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how to attack the width issue where an input field auto sizes untill max width then wraps. You could use a monospace font inside the text field so that you could use javascript to monitor and control the growth of the box horizontally uptill the max width.

To approach the height auto grow you would be better using a textarea with it set to one row to begin with so it looks like an input box and then when the text auto wraps to the next row, which it will do, you can check the scollHeight of the textarea and check the actual height of the textarea, subtract them and you get the height you need to grow the textarea to stop the vertical scroll bars appearing.

The above will make the scroll bars flick on and off briefly while your javascript does it magic. You can use `overflow:auto;` to hide the scroll bars but then I don't know if scrollHeight will still read correctly. You will need to experiment.

Also take note on my comment above about setting an interval on keydown and checking the input length to stop the repeating key down text issue.

Comment: So what triggers the check for "scrollHeight?" I'm seeing that the scalable text area is possibly harder than checking it's container size... lol--I should start a second question. Couldn't I just set the line-height within the text area, and then (maybe upon reaching a certain character limit) change the height manually to double the line-height? This web app won't allow more than 2 lines...

Comment: I'd need to find the widest letter, and find out what the width of the container would be with that 'character limit per line' would be... and then find a way to query how many letters are currently entered one very 'keydown', so I can set the text area width to "# of letters" x "width of widest letter."

Comment: Each key press you check the number of characters entered to grow the box horizontally and then when you hit the max width stop checking for it. On each key press check the scrollHeight, if the scrollheight is more than the actual height of the text area then the text has wrapped onto a new line so extend the textarea rows...