# how to find the element is resized using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to find the element is resized using jQuery. I know we can able to find the window is resized using jQuery. I want to perform some action if the div is resized, how can i do that.

Thank you in advance..

Comment: How exactly is the div being resized?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check when a div resizes, using Javascript or Jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4223838/how-to-check-when-a-div-resizes-using-javascript-or-jquery)

Comment: If you know how to do it for the window did you not try the same thing for a div?

Answer (score 3):

```
$(element).resize(function(){ alert('I am resized'); });
```

Comment: @Sathya now answer the Lix comment answer...which is how exactly is the div resized.?

Comment: Javascript code 
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#1").click(function(){
      $("#ptag").width(10);
    });
    $("#2").click(function(){
      $("#ptag").width(100);
    });
    $("#ptag").resize(function(){
      alert(1);
    });
  });
Html code

<p id="ptag">Window resized <span>0</span> times.</p>
<button id="1">Trigger resize event for the window</button>
<button id="2">Trigger resize event for the window</button>


Scenario is like this.

Comment: @lix do you understand my question?

Comment: Hi guys i found a solution

`$('element').bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function() { alert("size changed"); });`

Comment: @Sathya +1 for letting me know new thing.

Answer (score 1):

We can find resize of the element using this

```
$('element').bind("DOMAttrModified", function() { alert("size changed"); });
```

Comment: These mutation events are deprecated!!!. check mozilla dn for more details - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events

Answer (score 0):

[.resize()](http://api.jquery.com/resize/) documentation.

```
$(element).resize(function(){ 
  //code here 
});
```